# External GPU to support extra monitors?

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors

I am using Dell XPS 13 7390 for work with Dell Dock WD19.

For regular in-office work my setup consists of two FullHD monitors and laptop screen (so 3 screens in total). Now I'd like to use just two monitors but with higher resolutions: 1 ultra wide and second LG DualUp. That would effectively mean desktop size comparable to 4 "regular" screens which will not work via dock and GPU that is embedded.

For this reason I started to think about buying external GPU connected through Thunderbolt3... will such setup work without an issue? Maybe I would need to run both GPUs in parallel to support entire desktop size? Also, will Ubuntu be able to easily switch between display modes when I disconnect eGPU/dock and work only on laptop for a while?

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Comment: Ok, I removed the last question where I asked for recommendation. Now it's purely about possibility of setting up certain configuration.

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; nor software stack (if appropriate; ie. Ubuntu LTS releases come with kernel stack choices which may/may-not apply to you as we have no idea as to product/release, let alone all releases having multiple desktop or TUI choice).  Your question as worded is still vague & unspecific, and seeking off-topic opinion.  This is a Q&S site; you ask a question with specifics, and people provide answers that will achieve it.  https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask